# "wouldn't rather do something" vs "would rather not do something"?

Tags: word-usage

I am asking to see whether "**wouldn't rather do something**" and "**would rather not do something**" can be used interchangeably?

In textbook, they use "**would rather not do something**" see [Cambridge grammar](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/would-rather-would-sooner)

But in real world, people may use "**wouldn't rather do something**" see [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MS31i5P-398) at **4:08**

Answer (score 4):

It's hard to imagine contexts where a speaker might say *I wouldn't rather do that* (I can only think of an emphatic refutation when the previous speaker has just said *I expect you would rather do that*).

In OP's linked example the woman asks *Are you sure you wouldn't rather have dinner with your friend?* The negation of ***wouldn't*** is because what she *means* is something along the lines of *Are you sure it's **not** true [that you would rather do that]?*

Take *I would like Britain to leave the EU.* If you're *not* a "Brexiteer", that can be negated into *I would **not** like Britain to leave the EU* or *I would like Britain **not** to leave the EU* (there's no substantial difference in meaning, just a shift of emphasis from *not wanting X* to *wanting [NOT] X*).

But with *I would rather die* the only natural negation is *I would rather not die.* Ordinarily, you'd only say *I would not rather die* when disagreeing with someone who implied you *might* (an unusual situation! :). Perhaps *Do you really want to be kept on life support? Are you sure you wouldn't rather die?*

Comment: check the Google results of "wouldn't rather do something" and "would rather not do something", you'll see that "would rather not do something" shows more results

Comment: @Tom: Comparing estimated google hits for those two strings has no real relevance to this issue. Bear in mind that *would rather not do **something*** would be a pretty unusual word sequence - more likely to appear in a *definition* than a "genuine utterance" (whereas *[We] would rather not do **anything*** is a normal thing to say). If there's something you still don't understand about the usages being discussed, please feel free to ask for further clarification.